# ASP.NET MVC - generating PDF raises Win32Exception (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm trying to generate some PDFs based on screenshots. When I'm launching the method locally, it works without any issue. However, when I deployed it on a client machine, I'm getting the error mentioned in the title. Here's the method :

```
public ActionResult GeneratePdf()
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
                gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                bmpScreenshot.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Pdf/myscreenshot.png"), ImageFormat.Png);

                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
                document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

                document.Open();
                DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
                document.Add(new Paragraph(dtNow.ToString() + " - Impression de rendez-vous"));
                System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Pdf/myscreenshot.png"));
                iTextSharp.text.Image jpgImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(myImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                jpgImg.ScaleAbsolute(800, 500);
                document.Add(jpgImg);
                document.Close();
                writer.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename =Impression_Qutenza.pdf");
                Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Any idea of what's going on ?

EDIT : The stack trace :

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Descripteur non valide]
   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation) +512
   AstellasSchedulerV2.Controllers.HomeController.GeneratePdf() +232
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted **will not** take an screenshot of your *web page running in a web browser*, it will take a screenshot of the *current screen of the PC that is running the web server*. "It worked" in your local PC for two reasons:

1- Your development PC has the server and the web browser running there at the same time.

2- The web server you are using for development is not running as a service.

Web applications deployed to Internet Information Server will run under the IIS service process, and a service process does not have access to the server screen, this is the reason for the error you are seeing in the stack trace.

Possible solutions:

1- Use a PDF processing library to produce a PDF file from scratch on the server using the same data that was used for serving the web page.

Or

2- Use an HTML-to-PDF conversion tool to produce the PDF file from an equivalent page requested locally on the server. Examples: [Wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) or [Amyuni WebkitPDF](https://www.amyuni.com/en/server/webkitpdf/) (*note: I work for Amyuni Technologies*)

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET code runs on server-side and when you call .CopyFromScreen() method it tries to access the screen on the server. And the code is not allowed to access the browser's screen. This security limitation is the must otherwise viruses and trojans would be able to steal info without user's permission.

1. There is a [commercial component](http://websitesscreenshot.com) to get a screenshot of the given URL (but the URL should be publicly available) from server-side code.
2. You may to capture the screenshot from the client-side code (to make the screenshot of what end-user see) with the [this solution](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) that actually takes HTML and renders it into image to mimic the original page.
3. Another solution is to implement your own end-user desktop utility (like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12898/Screen-Capturing)) or plugin/extension (like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/) for Google Chrome) that will be installed on end-user computer (with the permission of the end-user), will make a screenshot and will send it back to your server.